# How to get table's metadata from linked server (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How to get tables metadata from linked server/another database? The query below works ideally when running on the main server, but returns null if calls remote server or even another database.

```
select object_name(major_id)
from server.bd1.sys.extended_properties
```

Probably, it is caused that the specific path for metadata functions (like object_name()) is not defined. Hence, functions take data not from remote server/DB, but server and DB they are launched.

If it is true, would you prompt the specific path (DB, schema) of metadata functions that I could define path explicitly.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using direct query to the tables with metadata except using builtin functions

```
select 
c.name schma
,a.name tble
,b.name desc_categ
,b.value desc_name
from server.db.sys.objects a
join server.db.sys.extended_properties b on a.parent_object_id = b.major_id
join server.db.sys.schemas c on a.schema_id = c.schema_id
```